# Вычислить значение выражения в постфиксной форме

Tags: c, алгоритм

В символьной строке записано выражение из цифр и операций в постфиксной форме (знак операции после операндов).
Проверить правильность записи и найти значение выражения.
Пример: выражение `(2+3)*4-5*6` записывается в постфиксной форме как `23+4*56*-`
Помогите пожалуйста с задачей! Буду премного благодарен

Answer (score 1):

Числа - в стек, операции выполняешь над двумя последними значениями в стеке и результат помещаешь обратно. В качестве стека можно использовать массив достаточного размера.

```js
function calc(s) {
  var st = []

  for (var t of s) {
    switch(t) {
      case "+":
        var r = st.pop(), l = st.pop()
        st.push(l + r)
        break
        
      case "-":
        var r = st.pop(), l = st.pop()
        st.push(l - r)
        break
        
      case "*":
        var r = st.pop(), l = st.pop()
        st.push(l * r)
        break
        
      case "/":
        var r = st.pop(), l = st.pop()
        st.push(l / r)
        break
        
      default:
        st.push(+t)
    }
  }
  
  if (st.length !== 1) {
    throw new Error("Invalid expression")
  }
  
  return st.pop()
}

console.log(calc("23+4*56*-"))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, с этим разобрался. Но теперь проблема с вводом и выводом данных. Как это реализовать с вашим кодом??? Извините, если это очень тупо)

Comment: Какой ввод? о_О

Comment: Ну с клавиатуры вводится формула, вычисляется и выводится

Answer (score 0):

Вам просто нужно сделать обычный [Алгоритм_сортировочной_станции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Если поищите внимательно, то найдете даже реализации.

Comment: А если вопрос прочитать?

Comment: я решил чуть больше задачи, чем человек попросил:)

Comment: Вопрос про вычисление в постфиксной форме. А в ответе алгоритм для инфиксной. Ну ещё можно допилить до преобразования из инфиксной в постфиксную. Но вопрос-то вообще не об этом.